# C++: Why are these results different?

Tags: c++

Why is the output of these two examples different in C++?

```
int a=025; 
float b=5.5; 
cout<<a+b;
```

26.5

```
int a=25; 
float b=5.5; 
cout<<a+b;
```

30.5

Comment: 025 is in octal. = 21 decimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal):

> octal-literal is the digit zero (0) followed by zero or more octal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

So `025` is actually the octal literal corresponding to decimal `21` which is why your answers differ by 4 (`25-025` or `25-21`).

Comment: I just had a "oh duh" moment! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you have assigned "a" the value of an octal literal. It's not the same as decimal 25. It's equivalent to 21 decimal.